# Equivalent of window.addEventListener - Android Webview

Tags: android-webview

In my `javascript` application, I use the below code to listen to the data that was sent from a `javascript` file loaded on the server using `parent.postmessage`.

```
 window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        var response = event.data;
        if (response != null) {
           //Did something
        }

    }, false);
```

Currently, in Android I'm using

```
 WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

The URL is the same where there is a `javascript` loaded that sends some data using `parent.postmessage` on a button click. How can I receive it in Android?